# Motion of an object "halfway in" a gravitational field

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, relativity

As a thought experiment, imagine a very long girder, moving at a constant velocity through space. At some point, it passes close to a black hole, such that one end of the girder is experiencing time dilation from the gravitational field, relative to the measurements taken from the other end. 
My question is twofold:

1. Does the difference in clock times produce an apparent, *coordinate* deceleration, relative to each clock (due to the symmetry of time dilation)?
2. Is this apparent deceleration measurable by a third, far away observer?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Gravity is not some finite extent force, the entire object is subject to varying degrees of time dilation, it's just the part closer to the black hole experiences more time dilation than further parts

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your answer. Would you please clarify a bit, I'm afraid I don't take your meaning. (Note: the question has been edited for clarity.)

Comment: @CuriousDroid: you might want to view  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gcvq1DAM-DE   video of a very similar situation

Comment: @AdrianHoward: Thank you so much for your answer, that clears it right up for me.